# How do I grab this value from Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Say I have:

```
<div class="amt" id="displayFare-1_69-61-0" style="">
  <div class="per">per person</div>
  <div class="per" id="showTotalSubIndex-1_69-61-0" style="">Total $334</div>
    $293
</div>
```

I want to grab just the `$334`.  It will always have "Total $" but the id `showTotalSubIndex...` will be dynamic so I can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nokogiri xpath expression to iterate over all the div nodes
and scan the string for the 'Total $' Prefix like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse( open( "test.xml" ))
doc.xpath("//div/text()").each{ |t|
   tmp = t.to_str.strip
   puts tmp[7..-1] if tmp.index('Total $') == 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of these work:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('//div[@id]/text()').select{ |n| n.text['Total'] }.first.text.split.last
```

and

```
doc.search('//div/text()').select{ |n| n.text['Total'] }.first.text.split.last
```

The difference is the first should run a bit faster if you know the div you're looking for always has an `id`.

If the ID always starts with "showTotalSubIndex" you could use:

```
doc.at('//div[starts-with(@id,"showTotalSubIndex")]').first.text.split.last
```

and if you know there's only going to be one in the document, you can use:

```
doc.at('//div[starts-with(@id,"showTotalSubIndex")]').text.split.last
```

EDIT:

Ryan posits the idea the XML structure might be consistent. If so:

```
doc.at('//div[2]').text[/(\$\d+)/, 1]
```

:-)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than finding the text:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
html.css("div.amt").children[1].text.gsub(/^Total /, '')
```

I assume here that the HTML is structured in such a way that the second child of any `div.amt` tag is the value that you're after, and then we'll just grab the text of that and gsub it.